# when is memory allocated for value types in c#?

Tags: c#, memory-management

```
static void Main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    j=10;
    i=2;
}
```

Is the memory allocated in stack for variables in the order in which their declaration appears or will it be allocated as they are initialized?

I think variables are loaded onto stack in the order in which they are declared while peers argue otherwise. So, according to them j is pushed onto stack first while i argue that i is pushed to stack first. who is correct?

Comment: if this is the only code in Main, building in Release mode might remove them completely from generated  IL code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does declaring a variable already occupy memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140630/does-declaring-a-variable-already-occupy-memory)

Comment: If you care what the order of those two variables is on the stack, you're doing something wrong in your program.  You should be writing your program in such a way that it doesn't matter.  The very idea of a stack is itself an implementation detail, let alone when and how variables are added to it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can not know the exact order of stack allocations.

Operations may be reordered by both the compiler and the processor for optimization purposes. And as Ehsan already pointed out in a comment, your code might not even be executed at all when a release build is used.

Have a look at this article [The C# Memory Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/jj863136), it may help explain why the exact order of allocation is not really something you can know beforehand.